# Learning discourses of Chabad Rebbes

Tags: torah-study, chasidut-hasidism, chabad

The Rebbes of Chabad during their own lifetimes published a [notable number of books](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Paradoxical_Ascent_to_God/7CGpBCTsoysC) (see p.37 there), such as Tanya, Torah Ohr and Derech Mitzvosecha. These are, I presume, regularly learned by Chabad Hasidim. However, there are many more volumes of Maamorim/Sichos from the various Rebbes which must in total run hundreds of volumes. There are [27 of the 1st Rebbe, Maamarei Admor Hazaken](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HAR-SM69) , [19 of the 2nd Rebbe Maamarei Admor Hamtzoe](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HMR-SM.SB), [~37 of the 3rd Ohr Hatorah](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HTZ-OT.S), [26 of the 4th Toras Shmuel](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HRM-TS.S), [~32 of the 5th](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HRR-SM.S), [21 of the 6th](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HFR-SM.SB), [and 39 in Likkutei Sichos alone of the most recent Rebbe](https://store.kehotonline.com/prodinfo.asp?number=HRE-LS.S).

How, practically, can these be studied? Are they regularly learned by Hasidim or are they just for reference? It seems like an enormous amount to get through, much of which was only published in the 20th century. They mostly are around the parshah of the year so I guess that's a starting point, but I try to learn my 3-volume set of Midrash Rabbah on Shabbos on the same schedule and it's time-intensive.

Comment: They're still being published actually. As with the rest of Torah, לא עליך המלאכה לגמור ולא אתה בן חורין ליבטל ממנה and לעולם ילמוד אדם תורה במקום שלבו חפץ and עשה לך רב והסתלק מן הספק.

Comment: There are certain "classics" that are regularly studied and others that are less so, but it heavily depends on where you're holding. There's no one-size-fits-all approach.

Comment: Chitas & HaYom Yom is every day. Torah Ohr & Likkutei Torah of the Alter Rebbe for the parsha are erev Shabbat and Shabbat. Many people try to follow "kviyut HaShanah" for the balance. Because the order of the year varies each year according to different annual length of the solar and lunar cycles, it points to which years from previous Rebbes are relevant and apply for the current year. That's on top of regular learning in Shas, kabbalah and halacha.

Comment: *They mostly are around the parshah of the year...* Yes and no. Many maamarim, especially within [hemshechim](https://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9A), use the parsha as an introductory header/footer with only a tenuous connection to the body of the maamar. But those in Likkutei Torah/Torah Ohr (a.k.a. the chassidishe parsha) tend to stay more on topic. It can be a little dense and challenging, but it's also foundational to much of the later chassidus.

Comment: That planning around the year is very interesting! Thanks for the info

Comment: This all revolves around the general principle of being a "man of the times". The specific Heavenly influence of every hour of every day follows the precise way that G-d has established the expression of time in the universe. If you have ever said Tikkun Leil Shavuot, you may have noticed the various permutations of G-d's names for each  hour. That is the same concept. So the specific subject according to parsha division, the solar and lunar cycles follows the same thing. This practice is also seen in all kabbalistic sources. It is an ancient practice.